# Сокрытие лицензиионного соглашение кода

Tags: лицензирование

Многие участки кода, в различных ипостасях, в начале файлов зачастую содержат обширный текст лицензионного соглашения. Яркий пример - библиотека Qt.

При публикации, обмене, пересылке такое предоставление информации неудобно, особенно если текст лицензионного соглашения больше самого кода.

**Вопрос**

Eсть ли легальный способ убрать текст лицензионного соглашения в более другие места так, чтобы не ущемлять права авторов, и, собственно, не нарушать тем самым те же соглашения?

**Примеры навскидку**

- вырезать текст соглашения, скопировать в отдельный файл и распространять архивом, т.е. файл(ы) кода + текстовой файл лицензионного соглашения
- предоставлять самописный "вьювер", который сможет прятать текст лицензионного соглашения под спойлер
- etc ...

Интересует любая инфа, кроме "имхо-ов".

Comment: Если Вы пользуетесь продуктами JetBrains (resharper для студии, или IDE типа Idea, PHPStorm и т.д.) - есть что-то типа конструкции `#region RegionName`, потом код который хотите скрывать-раскрывать, `#endregion`. После добавления в код, чуть левее от области с кодом появятся стрелки, позволяющие скрыть регионы. Хотя, по идее, если Вы пользуетесь этими продуктами, там уже можно так скрыть.

Comment: Увы, пока пользую исключительно QtCreator, ну и Far/Midnight Commander.